# Determinant of block matrix with off-diagonal blocks conjugate of each other.

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am working on finding the determinant of the following block matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
C & D \\
D^* & C \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $C$ and $D$ are $4 \times 4$ matrices with complex entries that do not commute. I have looked up a theorem that states
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{pmatrix}=\det(A-B)\det(A+B),
$$
when $A=D$ and $B=C$, but does there exist a similar simplification for my situation?

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: Was that Theorem found by You?

Comment: @RAM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $C$ is invertible [otherwise use the matrix $C - \lambda I$ in place of $C$ for that will certainly be invertible for infinitely many $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$].

Write $\begin{pmatrix} C & D \\ D^{*} & C \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ D^{*}C^{-1} & I \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} C & D \\ 0 & C - D^{*}C^{-1}D \end{pmatrix}$